# Unity3d - How to show model edges in game?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want the same effect as the Unity editor when an object clicked, same as the top on the picture.

The camera view at bottom show that no any edges on model.

I google a bit, there are many topic about wireframe and edge detection, but i cant find anything useful about showing the inner edges.

[image]

Comment: This question should be posted on [Game Development Stack Exchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @devpuh No, it doesn't. While Game Dev will accept and answer programming problems related to game development, the primary focus is "would a *game developer* be more suited to answer this question than an *any software developer?*" Such as, "[Why put cheat codes in games?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/150556/what-are-the-advantages-of-putting-cheat-codes-into-a-game)" or "[Creating a non-inflationary progress system?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/150655/how-to-create-a-non-inflationary-player-progress-system-rpg)"

Answer (score 1):

You need a [wireframe shader](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/21897). That link is one of many (and free).

For your specific use-case, you also want...

- Rendering the object normally while the wireframe is visible
- Be able to enable/disable the wireframe

Which means you need a method of knowing what object is "selected" and enabling either [a shader tag](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-SubShaderTags.html) which you can set once or [rendering the object a second time](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Graphics.DrawMesh.html) with a new material, but have to draw the object manually every frame.

Comment: I tried wireframe shader before, the problem is such shader outline all little triangles on mesh. As you can see on my photo, the unity editor highlight object by outline major wireframe rather than all triangles.

Comment: @Shitman Unity probably has a custom shader they use that determines if a given edge is on the "outside" or not. I don't know how its done.

Answer (score 0):

Since I had same, I wrote custom shader.
Code Listing :

```
Shader "DESS/WireframeShader"
{
    Properties
    {
        _WireColor("Edges Color", Color) = (0,0,0,1)
        _WireThickness("Edge Thickness", RANGE(0, 800)) = 100
        _WireSmoothness("Edge Smoothness", RANGE(0, 20)) = 3
        _AlbedoColor("Albedo Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType" = "Opaque" }
        LOD 200

        Pass
        {
        CGPROGRAM
            // Use shader model 3.0 target, to get nicer looking lighting
            #pragma target 3.0

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma geometry geom

            uniform sampler2D _MainTex;
            uniform float4 _MainTex_ST;

            struct Input
            {
                float2 uv_MainTex;
            };

            fixed4 _WireColor;
            fixed4 _AlbedoColor;

            uniform float _WireThickness;
            uniform float _WireSmoothness;

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 texcoord0 : TEXCOORD0;
                UNITY_VERTEX_INPUT_INSTANCE_ID
            };

            struct v2g
            {
                float4 projSpaceVertex : SV_POSITION;
                float2 uv0 : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 worldSpacePosition : TEXCOORD1;
                UNITY_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO
            };

            struct g2f
            {
                float4 projSpaceVertex : SV_POSITION;
                float2 uv0 : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 worldSpacePosition : TEXCOORD1;
                float4 dist : TEXCOORD2;
                UNITY_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO
            };

            v2g vert(appdata v)
            {
                v2g o;
                UNITY_SETUP_INSTANCE_ID(v);
                UNITY_INITIALIZE_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO(o);
                o.projSpaceVertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.worldSpacePosition = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex);
                o.uv0 = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.texcoord0, _MainTex);
                return o;
            }


            [maxvertexcount(3)]
            void geom(triangle v2g i[3], inout TriangleStream<g2f> triangleStream)
            {
                float2 p0 = i[0].projSpaceVertex.xy / i[0].projSpaceVertex.w;
                float2 p1 = i[1].projSpaceVertex.xy / i[1].projSpaceVertex.w;
                float2 p2 = i[2].projSpaceVertex.xy / i[2].projSpaceVertex.w;

                float2 edge0 = p2 - p1;
                float2 edge1 = p2 - p0;
                float2 edge2 = p1 - p0;

                float area = abs(edge1.x * edge2.y - edge1.y * edge2.x);
                float wireThickness = 800 - _WireThickness;

                g2f o;

                o.uv0 = i[0].uv0;
                o.worldSpacePosition = i[0].worldSpacePosition;
                o.projSpaceVertex = i[0].projSpaceVertex;
                o.dist.xyz = float3((area / length(edge0)), 0.0, 0.0) * o.projSpaceVertex.w * wireThickness;
                o.dist.w = 1.0 / o.projSpaceVertex.w;
                UNITY_TRANSFER_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO(i[0], o);
                triangleStream.Append(o);

                o.uv0 = i[1].uv0;
                o.worldSpacePosition = i[1].worldSpacePosition;
                o.projSpaceVertex = i[1].projSpaceVertex;
                o.dist.xyz = float3(0.0, (area / length(edge1)), 0.0) * o.projSpaceVertex.w * wireThickness;
                o.dist.w = 1.0 / o.projSpaceVertex.w;
                UNITY_TRANSFER_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO(i[1], o);
                triangleStream.Append(o);

                o.uv0 = i[2].uv0;
                o.worldSpacePosition = i[2].worldSpacePosition;
                o.projSpaceVertex = i[2].projSpaceVertex;
                o.dist.xyz = float3(0.0, 0.0, (area / length(edge2))) * o.projSpaceVertex.w * wireThickness;
                o.dist.w = 1.0 / o.projSpaceVertex.w;
                UNITY_TRANSFER_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO(i[2], o);
                triangleStream.Append(o);
            }

            fixed4 frag(g2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                float minDistanceToEdge = min(i.dist[0], min(i.dist[1], i.dist[2])) * i.dist[3];

                float4 baseColor = _AlbedoColor * tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv0);

                // Early out if we know we are not on a line segment.
                if (minDistanceToEdge > 0.9)
                {
                    return fixed4(baseColor.rgb,0);
                }

                // Smooth our line out
                float t = exp2(_WireSmoothness * -1.0 * minDistanceToEdge * minDistanceToEdge);
                fixed4 finalColor = lerp(baseColor, _WireColor, t);
                finalColor.a = t;

                return finalColor;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```